# string replace inside input text

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a string  like this:
$string1 = DO"C OR $string2= MV'C
and I have a input text Like This

```
<input type="text" value="">
```

if I am placing the string MV'C Like This

```html
<input type="text" value="MV'C">
```

every thing is ok
but if I put the DO"C String it brakes because the "

is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be solved in two ways.

1. using single quotes to wrap the text.

`<input type="text" value='DO"C' />`

2. using HTML Entities : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

`<input type="text" value="DO&quot;C" />`

Answer (score 0):

Always escape special symbols in javascript such as ' or " with a backslash like so `\"` or `\'`

as for html:`&#34;` for doublequotes "
and `&#39;` for single quotes '

Comment: thank U very useful!!!